# Add text at the end of specific lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I know how to add something to the end of every line, but how to add text at the end of the lines containing specific words.

```
Some line of text here
Tomatoes Oranges
Mili Deci Centi
Some line of text there
Fire Flame 
Dog Cat
Tall Small
Some line of text with more text
Mother farher
-------
```

I want to add characters at the end of the lines containing "Some line", something like this:

```
Some line of text here EXTRATEXT
Tomatoes Oranges
Mili Deci Centi
Some line of text there EXTRATEXT
Fire Flame 
Dog Cat
Tall Small
Some line of text with more text EXTRATEXT
Mother farher
-------
```

The lines end in different characters, so I need to search for a pattern that is inside the line, and add text at the end of those line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the following pattern:

```
Some line.*
```

With:

```
$0 EXTRATEXT
```

This matches from `Some line` up to the end of the line (`.*`, as `.` matches any character but a newline).

You can then replace the whole match (`$0`) with itself followed by the extra text you want.

Comment: Per info; when you have weird encoded files and maybe even hidden characters, these `awk`-like matching patterns might fail on you.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer if you deem it to work best in your case.

Comment: No complicated lines for me, I tried your method but i probably didn't fully understood it, nothing happened when I tried it in textpad...

Answer (score 0):

`[a-zA-Z]+\n` or `\w+\n` or mutliple `\n+` at the end if you want to clean empty lines too. Finally if it's important that the word is capital on the firs letter: `[A-Z][a-zA-Z]+\n`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try delimiting the regex pattern with a line-break, or a carriage return.

I think it might be achieved with \r\n at the end of the regex, on Notepad++.